# Accessing nested objects in array using each helper in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper, handlebars.java

I have data in this format

```
"numbers":[
        {
            "callFlow":{
                "type":"RING-ONE"
            },
            "number":"111111111"
        }
 ]
```

and my html looks likes this

```
{{#each numbers}}
{{number}}
{{callFlow.type}}
{{/each}}
```

Expected Output is

```
111111111
RING-ONE
```

But I get Output as

```
111111111
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly.

Comment: I am using handlebars in jsreport maybe that is an issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
{{#each numbers}}
 {{this.number}}
 {{this.callFlow.type}}
{{/each}}
```